# Why is my styled component not rendering as specified using GatsbyJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am currently trying to get myself familiar with the basics of React having previously employed a web development workflow using conventional HTML/CSS/JS. I am using GatsbyJS in conjunction with styled components and encountering the following problem.

I am defining and exporting a styled component named `Header` as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

// header.js

const HeaderWrapper = styled.div`
margin: 3rem auto;
background: black;
padding: 16px;
`

const SiteTitle = styled.h1`
font-size: 32px;
color: white;
`

const Header = props => (
    <HeaderWrapper>
        <SiteTitle>
            {props.siteTitle}
        </SiteTitle>
    </HeaderWrapper>
)

export default Header
```

I am then using the exported `Header` component in my index.js as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "../components/header"

// index.js

export default () => (
    <Header siteTitle="This is my Site" />
)
```

However, when viewing my site the text "This is my Site" is being rendered without any of the styles specified in my `header.js` file. I can’t seem to figure out what I’m doing wrong so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance.

Edit: I added a screenshot of the rendered site (including Chrome Developer tab) below.

https://ibb.co/3FCq751

Comment: does this still happen if you replace `const Header = props => (` with `export defaults () => (` ?

Comment: What happens if you put `import styled from "styled-components";` into `index.js`?

Comment: @ZektorH replacing `const Header = props => (` with `export default () => (` results in a "failed to compile" error (regardless of whether I keep or remove the `export default Header` line.

Comment: @MattCroak Nothing happens apart from a `no-unused-vars` error in the console: `2:8  warning  'styled' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars`

Comment: I've just tried your example exactly as-is in one of my Gatsby pages and it worked right away.  I've used styled components in React sites and Gatsby sites.  The only thing I can now think of is that you've installed styled-components, but not the gatsby plugin for styled-components.  Have a look at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/styled-components/